# How is 'match' implemented in Haskell's FGL to be O(1)?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, graph-algorithm

In Haskell's Functional Graph Library (FGL), most of the graph algorithms depend on the 'match' function, which, given a `Node n` and a `Graph g`, returns `c & g'`, where `c` is the `Context` of the `n`, and `g'` is the rest of the graph (which contains no references to `n`).

The only way I can see of doing this is be examining each of the contexts in `g` and removing any edges which refer to `n` and adding them to the context `c`. This would take linear time, I believe.

Martin Erwig, who wrote the library, suggests in [this](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~erwig/papers/InductiveGraphs_JFP01.pdf) paper that this transformation can be done in constant or at least sub-linear time. Can anyone explain to me how this is accomplished?

Comment: A very high level overview - most of the work in the `match` function for the most common graph implementation uses the `lookup` function from the `IntMap` module. This is `O(min(n,W))` where `n` is the number of elements in the map, and `W` is the size in bits of an int (normally either 32 or 64). So the lookup is linear in n, up to a maximum of n=32 or n=64, after which is it constant - in particular, it is asymptotically O(1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`match` is defined in the [Graph](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fgl/5.4.2.4/doc/html/Data-Graph-Inductive-Graph.html#g:4) typeclass, so the implementation of that function depends on the datatype that implements the typeclass.

The package comes with two implementations, [one using Patricia trees](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fgl/5.4.2.4/doc/html/src/Data-Graph-Inductive-PatriciaTree.html#Gr), [one using regular trees](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/fgl/5.4.2.4/doc/html/src/Data-Graph-Inductive-Tree.html#Gr).  You can view the source for either yourself.

For example, the Patricia tree implementation:

```
import           Data.Graph.Inductive.Graph
import           Data.IntMap (IntMap)
import qualified Data.IntMap as IM
import           Data.List
import           Data.Maybe
import           Control.Arrow(second)


newtype Gr a b = Gr (GraphRep a b)

type GraphRep a b = IntMap (Context' a b)
type Context' a b = (IntMap [b], a, IntMap [b])

type UGr = Gr () ()


instance Graph Gr where
    -- ...
    match           = matchGr
    -- ...

matchGr :: Node -> Gr a b -> Decomp Gr a b
matchGr node (Gr g)
    = case IM.lookup node g of
        Nothing
            -> (Nothing, Gr g)

        Just (p, label, s)
            -> let !g1 = IM.delete node g
                   !p' = IM.delete node p
                   !s' = IM.delete node s
                   !g2 = clearPred g1 node (IM.keys s')
                   !g3 = clearSucc g2 node (IM.keys p')
               in
                 (Just (toAdj p', node, label, toAdj s), Gr g3)
```

[`lookup` and `delete` on IntMaps have O(min(n,W)) runtime](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-IntMap-Strict.html), which is effectively constant on a given machine with a set integer width (`W`).

So that just leaves `clearPred`, `clearSucc`, and `toAdj`:

```
clearSucc :: GraphRep a b -> Node -> [Node] -> GraphRep a b
clearSucc g _ []       = g
clearSucc g v (p:rest) = clearSucc g' v rest
    where
      g' = IM.adjust f p g
      f (ps, l, ss) = (ps, l, IM.delete v ss)


clearPred :: GraphRep a b -> Node -> [Node] -> GraphRep a b
clearPred g _ []       = g
clearPred g v (s:rest) = clearPred g' v rest
    where
      g' = IM.adjust f s g
      f (ps, l, ss) = (IM.delete v ps, l, ss)
```

`adjust` is also `O(min(n,W))`, so we don't need to worry about that.  Both `clearSucc` and `clearPred` recurse through each element in the adjacency list, though, so that's O(degree) combined.

```
toAdj :: IntMap [b] -> Adj b
toAdj = concatMap expand . IM.toList
  where
    expand (n,ls) = map (flip (,) n) ls
```

`toAdj` creates a new edge list, which is O(max(|V|,|E|)), but this is constructed lazily, so we don't need to worry about this unless it's used.